# PHP form not working after jQuery replaces an INPUT object

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with a select object. Options are generated using PHP from mySQL DB. I also have a 'new'option available. if the user selects 'new' I am using jQuery - replaceWith function to change the select object to an input type='text' object.

This all works great, except after submitting the form the PHP $_POST['description'][0] is empty. Why would this be the case? Below I have copied a snap of the select object and the jQuery.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('select#description').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'new')
        var x = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" name="description" id="description">');
        $('input#description').attr('name', x);
        $('input#description').attr('id', x);
    });
});
```

---

HTML/PHP:

```
<td>
   <select id='description' name='description[$i]'>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option name='[$i]' value='new'>new</option>";
                        echo $list = $this->desc_list();
echo "      </select>
 </td>
```

This is the output I am looking for:

```
<select id='description' name='description[0]'>
<option value></option>
<option value='new'>new</option>
<option value='1'></option>
</select>
```

Where the value='1' is there is no description because when PHP saved the last entry it was empty.  Once the user selects 'new' the code changes the select object to this:

```
<input type='text' name='description[0]' id='description[0]'>
```

Next page code can be simple like

```
echo $_POST['description'][0]
```

But it will not echo what was typed in the textbox.  Why is the last entry empty?

Comment: can you show the output if the HTML/PHP? what you gave is the code itself..

Comment: What does `var_export($_POST)` say? Anything related to `description` in there?

Comment: sorry i have no idea how to use 'var_export($_POST)' i just know that once I click submit and ask PHP to echo the $_POST it shows up empty, could this be because PHP does not recognize the input because it was replaced by jQuery?

Comment: Please post a phpfiddle or something

Comment: here is the or something you asked for Prodikl im not sure if this will help you understand better. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7id-4fc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer got accepted: The solution described below is not correct. The correspondence within the comments of this answer seems to have lead to the solution.

Your problem appears to be the way you attempt to echo the POST-variable:
`echo $_POST['description'][0]` will never provide the value of your input-text, as the name of this field is "description[0]", thus you will need to call `echo $_POST['description[0]']`.

If this does not solve your issue and as you are not familiar with var_export: Try to put a `print_r($_POST);` above/below your while-loop in page2.php and let us know about the output.

Comment: thank you for the guidance. I changed my code to work another way however I would still like to learn what I have done wrong with this code. 
print_r($_POST); gave :

Array ( [project_no] => 2 [pin] => n_projects [contracting_no] => 1 [lines] => 3 
[asset_no] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) 
[quantity] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 5 ) 
[unit_price] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 6 ) 
[Save] => Save )

I would need to see the following in the list but its not there.
[description] => Array ( [0] => apples [1] => pears [2] => oranges )

Comment: I think because jQuery replaces the input after page load that the it is no longer regarded as part of the form is this possible?

Comment: Actually I just proved myself wrong, apparently the form submit actually converts "['description[0]']" to "['description']['0']", I seem to still need to learn myself.  
I took the code of the phpfiddle and tested it locally – and it works. My Output (including print_r):  
Array ( [description] => Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test3 ) [submit] => submit ) test1test2test3. Do you change the form-submit via jQuery at any point?

Comment: LOL just my luck that the code I write works for you but not for me. There is nothing more in jQuery changing this form at all. Could it be because im using chrome as my browser, there really isnt anything else I can then think off. but good to know the code is working.

Comment: I would suggest to export this problem to a standalone version, without any surrounding code (as I did). I used two php-files, removed the surrounding function of the mainfile and included jQuery and your JS in an echo within the mainfile. It works for me in Firefox & Chrome
It would be interesting whether it works as standalone version for you?

Answer (score 1):

Because you've replace "description[$i]" with "description"

Comment: var x = description[$i] then i used $('input#description').attr('name', x); to change the name back to description[$i]